# "hiding/showing" elements and change button background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code works great hiding/showing (Iamhiden) only.

**HTML:**

```html
 <nav id="Iamhiden"></nav>
 <button id="THeSummoner" onclick="toggle_visibility('Iamhiden');"></button>
```

**CSS:**

```css
 #Iamhiden{}
 #THeSummoner{
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-image: url(../Images/mobile-icon-1.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin: 22px 0px auto 0px;
      padding: 0;
      border-style: none;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: transparent;
}
```

**JS:**

```js
function toggle_visibility(Iamhiden) {
   var e = document.getElementById(Iamhiden);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

https://app.box.com/s/qy27mxja53tzucyzijbbiuhmd29bn40i
https://app.box.com/s/8rom8cax3esmws62aj64p5yhwkeass8k

But I don't want it to hide/show (Iamhiden) I only want it to change the background-image for (THeSummoner).

**JS - 2:**

```js
function toggle_visibility(Iamhiden) {
   var e = document.getElementById(Iamhiden);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
      **document.getElementById(THeSummoner).style.background-image=url(../Images/mobile-icon-1.png);**
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById(THeSummoner).style.background-image=url(../Images/xmnu.png);
}
```

I tried **JS - 2** but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Using javascript to style the background of an element you will want to use `style.backgroundImage="url()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **THeSummoner** variable, so you have to specify the element Id as string, not as variable:

```
document.getElementById('THeSummoner')
```

Now you can change the background image of the element like this:

```
document.getElementById('THeSummoner').style.backgroundImage = "url('type_path_here')";
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/42joe84p/2/

Comment: Moaz Walid Mabrok didn't storage the getElementById() in a variable so i'm not sure why you have mentioned it? Moaz Walid Mabrok obviously thought the javascript style property would be the same as the CSS property. Why the mention of variables?

Comment: What? I wrote that he doesn't have any variable with the name of THeSummoner, so he cannot use it as parameter in getElementById() function, because it's undefined. In this case the object is null and a null object has no style property. So he has to change this to string (or he can declare a variable with this name and set the value as 'THeSummoner') because in getElementById() function you have to use string as parameter: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp